# What is wrong with this?

Tags: comments, pagination

with this script I wanna ask if the pagination for comments has more sites than 0 and if its so, I wanna use a custom title.

But I got an PHP mistake...can anybody please tell me whats wron with that ?

```
<?php 
$page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');
if ($page_comment > 0);?>
test
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the syntax; there's a semicolon after the if **condition**. Try this:

```
<?php 
$page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');
if ($page_comment > 0): ?>
test
<?php endif; ?>
```

Alternative PHP syntax:

```
<?php 
$page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');
if ($page_comment > 0){ ?>
test
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Awesome. You can mark this answer as the correct :)

Comment: Very good there is one question more to that perhaps you know that too ? :)

Comment: I suggest you to open another question explaining precisely your problem

Comment: I will do now...please look :)

Comment: Remember to mark your questions as answered http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers